# Button visibility on screen rotation no working for more than one button

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to restore a string in textView and button visibility state on screen rotation. It works if I use only one button and comment out the rest. But doesn't work for all buttons. Please suggest any possible reason for this.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outInstanceState) {  
super.onSaveInstanceState(outInstanceState);

outInstanceState.putString(savedName, colorView.getText().toString());
outInstanceState.putInt(savedWhiteBtn, (Integer) whiteColorButton.getVisibility());
outInstanceState.putInt(savedBlackBtn, (Integer) blackColorButton.getVisibility());
outInstanceState.putInt(savedRedBtn, (Integer) redColorButton.getVisibility());
outInstanceState.putInt(savedGreenBtn, (Integer) greenColorButton.getVisibility());
outInstanceState.putInt(savedYellowBtn, (Integer) yellowColorButton.getVisibility());
}   


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

colorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
whiteColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonWhite);
blackColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBlack);
redColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
yellowColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYellow);
greenColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGreen);

if(savedInstanceState != null){
    colorView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(savedName));
    whiteColorButton.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(savedWhiteBtn));
    blackColorButton.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(savedBlackBtn));
    redColorButton.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(savedRedBtn));           
    greenColorButton.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(savedGreenBtn));
    yellowColorButton.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(savedYellowBtn));
}
else{
    colorView.setText(getString(R.string.strStart));
}
}
```

Comment: Are the keys of outInstanceState all unique? ie: savedWhiteBtn, savedBlackBtn, savedRedBtn all are different values?

Comment: Ya, all keys are unique. The values of  savedWhiteBtn, savedBlackBtn, savedRedBtn change on some activity. There are all declared as private String in class.

Comment: If they keys are changing you will need to update the value in the map.  It is a really bad idea to allow those values to change, its better to use constants for map keys in this case.  They should be private static final's.